# Updating an object's deep property with Redux reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following structure. I have a `Company` object which contains many `Person` objects in an array.

```
companies: CompanyInterface = {
   persons: PersonInterface[] = []
}
```

I'm trying to show the persons that belongs to this company in a table. However, when I add/delete persons to the persons array, it should automatically be updated.

Right now my reducer looks like this:

```
// Initial state
companies: CompanyInterface[];

// Reducer
case Constants.GLOBAL_COMPANY_ADD_PERSON:
  [action.payload.person].concat(state.companies.filter(company => company.id === action.payload.id)[0].persons));

  return {
    ...state
  };
```

Although I can verify concat works properly (I can see `[Person]` when I consolle log it) it doesn't update anything on the store.

So what is the best way to update an array in Redux, which is a property in the parent object?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at `Array.prototype.concat`, as it does not mutate the array in place, but [returns a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). In your example you are not mutating the state.

Instead, you need to replace the old value with the new one. For instance:

```
case 'ADD_ELEMENT':
   const { elements: previousElements } = state;
   const newElement = action.payload;
   const newElements = previousElements.concat(newElement)
   return {
      ...state,
      elements: newElements
   };
```

Comment: And when I mutate it, React complains about mutating the data in reducers. Can you elaborate a bit? Also, where do you get newElement from? It is not a company object. action.payload is an object that should be pushed inside company's property.

Comment: The example is to illustrate what the pattern should be, see http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html Your piece of code is clearly doing nothing. You are simply concatenating the new person to previous, without storing the return value in any variable and then returning the previous state. As @momentator explained to you, you need to store that value in a variable and then return a new state with `companies` updated.

Comment: I tried Momenator's example too. I get JS errors which says "There was a mutation detected inside Reducer which is forbidden.". I'm a bit confused actually.